# Multiple full joins in one query on multiple tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a database with multiple tables, I wish to show all contents from every table with one query (that I will use later for a research in the database).

[view of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOHHH.png)

I've tried with two tables

```
[SELECT 
    reception.num_courrier, reception.date_recep, reception.expediteur, reception.objet, 
    lect_prefet.date_lect_prefet, lect_prefet.instructions, lect_prefet.caractere 
FROM
    reception 
FULL JOIN 
    lect_prefet ON reception.num_courrier = lect_prefet.num_courrier][2]
```

but it returns an error.

I'm using 10.4.14-MariaDB version.

[full join query error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sjV6.jpg)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: the full join query error image is not even readable...please put a higher-resolution image

Comment: @ Zeeshan Arif, a new image was uploaded,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses multiple `left join`s, starting with all available ids:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT r.num_courrier
      FROM reception r
      UNION -- on purpose to remove duplicate 
      SELECT l.num_courrier 
      FROM lect_prefet l
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     reception r
     USING (num_courrier) LEFT JOIN
     lect_prefet l
     USING (num_courrier);
```

This approach easily generalizes to more tables using the same key for the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM reception r
LEFT OUTER JOIN lect_prefet lp ON lp.num_courrier = r.num_courrier
LEFT OUTER JOIN lect_sg ls ON ls.num_courrier = r.num_courrier
LEFT OUTER JOIN ad ad ON ad.num_courrier = r.num_courrier
LEFT OUTER JOIN agt agt ON agt.num_courrier = r.num_courrier
```

If the above doesn't work, it would be great if you can provide an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example so that others can try on a live schema.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, you really helped me, this is what I expected, folowing the answer of @Gordon Linoff[ adding some rows] Thank you

```
    SELECT * FROM (
SELECT r.num_courrier FROM reception r UNION 
SELECT l.num_courrier FROM lect_prefet l UNION 
SELECT s.num_courrier FROM lect_sg s UNION 
SELECT g.num_courrier FROM agt g UNION 
SELECT d.num_courrier FROM ad d ) c 
LEFT JOIN reception r USING (num_courrier) 
LEFT JOIN lect_prefet l USING (num_courrier) 
LEFT JOIN lect_sg s USING (num_courrier) 
LEFT JOIN agt g USING (num_courrier) 
LEFT JOIN ad d USING (num_courrier);
```

[Expected
Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8LrX.jpg)